# set theory problem please help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove that **If** P(A ∪ B) = P(A) ∪ P(B) **Then** A ⊆ B or B ⊆ A.

The question before that was to prove the opposite: if A ⊆ B or B ⊆ A  then P(A ∪ B) = P(A) ∪ P(B), and i did..my answer was:

First let's show that P(A ∩ B) is a subset of P(A) ∩ P(B). Let S be an element of P(A ∩ B) i.e. S is a subset of A ∩ B. Then S is a subset of A and of B. So S is an element of P(A) and of P(B) and hence it is an element of P(A) ∩ P(B). So P(A ∩ B) is a subset of P(A) ∩ P(B).

Next show that P(A) ∩ P(B) is a subset of P(A ∩ B). This is pretty much just a reversal of the steps for the above, but let's just repeat it to minimize confusion. Let S be an element of P(A) ∩ P(B), then S is an element of P(A) and of P(B). So S is a subset of A and of B, meaning that S is a subset of A ∩ B. Thus S is an element of P(A ∩ B). So P(A) ∩ P(B) is a subset of P(A ∩ B).

this way just is a bit harder for me.

any help?

Comment: Did your unions become intersections?

Comment: Hint: The contrapositive is quite nice for the given problem.  If $A\not\subseteq B$ and $B\not\subseteq A$, then there is an element $x\in A$ such that $x\not\in B$ and there is an element $y\in B$ such that $y\not\in A$.  Now, find an element of $P(A\cup B)$ that is not in $P(A)\cup P(B)$.

Comment: so basically you can't since in p(aub) u won't have any common elements, so it will be empty, is that correct?

Comment: I can't really figure out your last comment.  Please make it more precise.  $P(A\cup B)$ won't be empty ...

Comment: if If A⊈B and B⊈A
then there is an element x∈A such that x∉B
and there is an element y∈B such that y∉A , then a and b don't have any common elements, so in p(a u b) it'll only contain the empty group?

Comment: Your statement is false, be careful with your quantifiers.  Just because $A$ and $B$ each have one element that the other doesn't have, they certainly have common elements.  The statement isn't *for all $x\in B$, $x\not\in A$*, it is *there exists $x\in B$ such that $x\not\in A$.*  The second statement only tells you that there's one $x$ that satisfies the conditions, not that all $x$'s satisfy the conditions.

Comment: right, sorry i got confused with intersections, so how do i start the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

We have $A\cup B\in\wp(A\cup B)$.

So if $\wp(A\cup B)=\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)$ then $A\cup B\in\wp(A)$ or $A\cup B\in\wp(B)$.

Comment: ohh thank you, got it. i have another question

N is a set of natural numbers N={0,1,2....,} . For every n⊆ N => An = {x∈ N | 0≤ x ≤ n}
prove or disprove:
∀n∈N ∀m∈N ((Am = {x2 | x∈An}) ↔ (m=n ^ n<2))

my answer is, and I'm not sure..if n<2, then the only options are 0 or 1, which make the left side wrong, is that correct?

Comment: but on the other hand, at first i thought, that both o and 1 ^2 will always give 0 and 1, so I'm not sure which one is right?